# How to correctly implement onBeforeDelete method in AbstractMongoEventListener using reactive mongo?

Tags: mongodb, spring-webflux, event-listener, reactive, reactor

I'm novice in reactive programming and now i trying to rewrite my test spring boot web application on reactive stack(web flux, reactor, reactive mongo).

My app it is simple library with 3 type of entities: Book, Genre, Author;
Book has a link on Genre and Author. In my old app without reactive stack when i tried to remove Genre or Author which linked with some Book, i handled it moment in onBeforeDelete method which was overrided in my class which extending from AbstractMongoEventListener.

It is look like this:

```
@Component
public class CascadeAuthorOrGenreDeleteMongoEventListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Object> {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AuthorRepository authorRepository;

    @Autowired
    private GenreRepository genreRepository;

    @Override
    public void onBeforeDelete(BeforeDeleteEvent<Object> event) {
        if (Objects.equals(event.getCollectionName(), "genre") || Objects.equals(event.getCollectionName(), "author")) {
            String id = String.valueOf(event.getSource().get("_id"));
            Optional<Genre> genre = genreRepository.findById(id);
            Optional<Author> author = authorRepository.findById(id);
            if (genre.isPresent()) {
                if (bookRepository.findFirstByGenre(genre.get()) != null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Genre has related books");
                }
            }
            if (author.isPresent()) {
                if (bookRepository.findFirstByAuthor(author.get()) != null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Author has related books");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now i trying to write the same code on reactive stack, I have already written some code example, but i'm not sure that is it correctly, maybe can i do it better with using reactive functions? I can't figure out with it by myself.

Here my example:

```
@Component
public class CascadeAuthorOrGenreDeleteMongoEventListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Object> {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AuthorRepository authorRepository;

    @Autowired
    private GenreRepository genreRepository;

    @Override
    public void onBeforeDelete(BeforeDeleteEvent<Object> event) {
        if (Objects.equals(event.getCollectionName(), "genre") || Objects.equals(event.getCollectionName(), "author")) {
            String id = String.valueOf(event.getSource().get("_id"));
            genreRepository.findById(id)
                    .zipWith(authorRepository.findById(id))
                    .flatMap(tuple -> {
                        final Genre genre = tuple.getT1();
                        final Author author = tuple.getT2();

                        return bookRepository.findFirstByAuthor(author)
                                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.fromCallable(Book::new))
                                .zipWith(bookRepository.findFirstByGenre(genre)
                                        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.fromCallable(Book::new)));
                    }).subscribe(tuple -> {
                            final Book bookByAuthor = tuple.getT1();
                            final Book bookByGenre = tuple.getT2();
            
                            if (bookByAuthor.getId() != null) {
                                throw new RuntimeException("Author has related books");
                            }
                            if (bookByGenre.getId() != null) {
                                throw new RuntimeException("Genre has related books");
                            }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Is it correct or exist way to do it better?**

Comment: Hi! Did you found a solution for this issue?

Comment: Hi, yes, i found